Running multiple bash scripts at once
I've like 10 repos running in the same machine, I some times change machines and want to deploy them automatically and fast so I made this script to execute each repo installation file at the same time two repos by two
#!/bin/bash

echo "Staring temp runner"


script_dir="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

temp_scripts_folder="$script_dir/temp"

mapfile -t scripts < <(find "$temp_scripts_folder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sh")

for ((i = 0; i < ${#scripts[@]}; i+=2)); do
    script1="${scripts[i]}"
    script2="${scripts[i+1]}"

    if [[ -n $script2 ]]; then

        echo "Script 1: $script1 and Script 2: $script2"

        echo "execution $script1"

        echo "logs are $script1.logs"
        sudo chmod +x "$script1" && "$script1" >> "$script1.logs" &


        echo "logs are $script2.logs"
        echo "execution $script2"

        sudo chmod +x "$script2" && "$script2" >> "$script2.logs" &

    else
        if [ -f "$script1" ]; then
            echo "Only one file is found: $script1"
            # Execute the script
            echo "execution $script1"
            sudo chmod +x "$script1" && "$script1" &
        else
            echo "File does not exist: $script1"
        fi
    fi
done

it runs multiple bash script files at the same time, all of them work fine but only two files don't work properly and IDK why
here's the content of the failed file
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/ubuntu
sudo mkdir -p azure
cd azure

if [ -d "Admin" ]; then
  cd /home/ubuntu/azure/Admin
  sudo git checkout dev
  sudo git pull origin dev

else
  sudo git clone https://some_url
  cd /home/ubuntu/azure/Admin
  sudo git checkout dev
  sudo rm -rf src/sharedModule
  sudo git rm --cached src/sharedModule
  sudo git submodule add https://some_url src/sh>fi

cd /home/ubuntu/azure/Admin/src/sharedModule
sudo git checkout main
sudo git pull origin main
cd /home/ubuntu/azure/Admin
sudo rm -rf nginx/logs
sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build nginx --no-cache
sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml down -v
sudo docker compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
sudo docker system prune -f
sudo docker volume prune -f
sudo docker image prune -f
sudo docker container prune -f
sudo docker network prune -f

the docker compose up -d does not work at all and not prints anything like it was never there

logs:

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
Already up to date.
Total reclaimed space: 0B
Total reclaimed space: 0B
Total reclaimed space: 0B
Total reclaimed space: 0B


Usual debugging thoughts: what if you ran them 1 script at a time instead of 2? What if you ran just the failing scripts? What if you switched their order? What if you replace the content of those script with ones that work? etc. etc. to narrow the problem down so you can pinpoint the exact circumstances that result in the failure. You may also want to add set -x at the top of your scripts so you can see what they're doing.

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78519272/7552

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As all suggested, it was an issue in the script I was trying to execute not the code running the script
after setting debugging set -x I found out why and fixed it in the script and all worked fine
